# 'OrderVm' does not contain a definition for 'Id'

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting a 'class doesn't contain a definition for property'. After spending my time finding a solution, I still don't know how to solve it. Although I declare in the ViewModel, it still gets a bug that 'OrderVm' does not contain a definition for 'Id'. I am kind of frustrated with this bug.

**OrderRepository.cs**

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<OrderVm>> GetAddressShipping(string userId)
        {
            var listOrder = await _dbContext.Orderings
                                    .Where(x => x.UserId.Equals(userId))
                                    .AsNoTracking()
                                    .ToListAsync();

            var listVm = listOrder.Select(x => new OrderVm
            {
                Id = x.Id, // this line causes the bug
                ClientName = x.Name,
                Address = x.Address,
                Phone = x.Phone,
                CreatedAt = x.CreatedAt,
            }).ToList();

            return listVm;
        }
```

**OrderVm.cs**

```
using System;
namespace RookieEShop.Shared
{
    public class OrderVm
    {
        public string ClientName { get; set; }

        public int Phone { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

        public int Id { get; set; } // The Id property has been declared
    }
}
```

After running the file, I get error below:

> OrderRepository.cs: error CS0117: 'OrderVm' does not contain a definition for 'Id'

Thanks for your reading. Hopefully, I will get a solution from you guys.

Updated: In the viewmodel, I have only one OrderVm class. [The all viewmodel class in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATuNW.png)

Comment: By deduction, its likely you have more than one `OrderVm` laying around. A quick fix might be `new RookieEShop.Shared.OrderVm`. However who knows what state your projects are in

Comment: @TheGeneral Thanks for your answering. Actually, in my ViewModel, I have only the OrderVm class.

Comment: Search the entire solution for `OrderVm`... if there is only one, then your build and source could be out of sync. Try clean and rebuild.

Comment: @TheGeneral Thanks for your solution. I tried your solution by adding RookieEShop.Shared.OrderVm in the Select. Unfortunately, It still gets the 'OrderVm' does not contain a definition for 'Id' bug. It is so frustrating :(.

Comment: So have you searched your whole solution for the occurrence of OrderVm

Comment: Guess: if this was a modification, have you _successfully_ rebuilt/recompiled (project, solution and/or dependencies)?

Comment: @TheGeneral I also searched the OrderVm in the entire solution, cleaned and rebuilt the solution. But, it still gets the below bug.

Comment: Is this xamarin or maui by any chance?

Comment: @EdSF I have not been building the program successfully since I added Id = x.Id in GetAddressShipping method. Without Id = x.Id, the program builds successfully. I can not understand what is going on with my code.

Comment: @TheGeneral No, I use the .NET MVC template for my project.

Comment: HI @TheGeneral, I know the reason that my program gets the above bug. Thanks, guys for helping me to find out the solution.

Comment: @SergioNguyen - glad to hear you resolved your problem.  If you want, you could add a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so others can know how you solved your problem.

Comment: @SergioNguyen Please add an answer sharing how you resolved your problem. Otherwise the question is of little value to anyone coming across this question with a similar issue.

Comment: @dbc Thanks guys for reminding me. I will add the answer to my question soon :).

Comment: @phuzi, thanks for reminding me. I will add the solution soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending my time to find out the reason behind my bug, I officially found the answer for my bug.
In the past, I deselected the build column of project "RookieEShop.Shared" in the Solution Property Pages (**Solution->Properties->Configuration Properties**). As a result, the system could not compile the new variable in the file, and it had caused the bug you see in my question. When I knew the reason, I select the build column in Solution Property Pages (you can see the picture below), my project worked properly as I expected.

For those who still get my bug although you have followed my solution, **please check your variable** is **declared with the public keyword or not**. If not, change your variable to public. It works properly.
[Solution Property Pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkb54.png)

Update: Because my reputation is not enough to add the image in my answer, you guys can follow the link. Sorry for the inconvenient.